# Design solution for custom serialization in a WCF service/client

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have been tasked with implementing custom serialization in a WCF service that receives/transmits large volumes of data.

I reviewed [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Serialization-43b3ee7a#content) example on MSDN to find a solution: the author creates a serialization attribute for his service contract and implements a serialization interface on each data contract class.

I like this idea, but in the example he simply demonstrates the project's correctness by launching a proxy channel in the main thread and having it obtain data. My client will be built out as a separate application, which complicates how it inherits the serialization attribute and data contracts.

I moved the serialization attribute and data contracts to their own library, and included references in both the service and client projects, so that they may both use them. In the generated code for the client's reference to the service, I added the attribute over the service contract/interface, and sure enough the serialization worked on the client side.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem? Is there a way to communicate a custom serialization over the metadata? I don't expect there to be a way, but I'm new to WCF programming. I'm worried that my current design might not be the best course of action, and perhaps there are WCF technologies that might better serve my purposes. Furthermore, if this service needs to be accessed by an application outside the .NET framework, my serialization library would be useless.

I've also realized that my approach kind of defeats the whole point of the service advertising it's data contracts: any client who communicates with the service has to ignore the data contracts in the metadata and use the classes found in the common library. If a client is ignorant of this common library, it will receive errors and null values for any operation contract it attempts.

I apologize if my question has been answered elsewhere, but so far I cannot find anything that addresses my specific design questions.

Comment: If you're using custom serialization, you can't really describe it in a meaningful way in metadata. Your approach with using a separate library seems correct and yes, it won't be usable outside of .net. You would have to describe your serialization method for implementation in other languages.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need custom serialization? Did you try binary formatter over TCP? Is it not enough effective?

Comment: Anyway it's better to simply your question a bit, it's too descriptive IMO.

Comment: @Shrike - The issue is that for a given service operation, the service will transmit back a very, very large set of data. Wrapping all of this data in XML and formatting that string with the binary formatter is still too big - I need something that can be as concise as possible - i.e. a byte stream that is correctly de-serialized on the other side. I apologize if I was too descriptive, but I have the philosophy that, when in doubt, give more information - not less.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander WCF has streaming option too.